# Сonsistency of the statistical estimate for the variance of the normal distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The confidence interval  of the $1 - \varepsilon$ level for the variance of the normal distribution $N(a; \sigma^2)$  is the following pair of statitics:
$$(\frac{nS^{2}}{t_{\varepsilon}^{(2)}}, \frac{nS^{2}}{t_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}}),$$ $t_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}\text{is a distribution quantile $\chi_{n-1}^{2}$ with probability $1 -\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$}; t_{\varepsilon}^{(2)} \text{is a distribution quantile $\chi_{n-1}^{2}$  with probability $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$}.$

$S^2$ is a sample variance.

I have a question: is the statistical data consistent for the parameter $\sigma^2$? I.e. do the statistical data converge in probability to $\sigma^2$?

It is clear that $S^2$ is a consistent estimate for $\sigma^2$. $t_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}$ tends to infinity. But then how exactly to calculate this limit?

Comment: As I understand it, you know that $S_n^2$ converges to $\sigma^2$ (in probability) and you would like to show that the two interval boundaries also converge to $\sigma^2$. Is that right? In that case, I think what you still need is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n/t_{\epsilon}^{(k)} = 1$. Maybe the following statement can help: For a $\delta$-quantile $q$ of $\chi^2_{n-1}$, it holds that $$n-1-2\sqrt{(n-1)\ln(1/\delta)}\leq q\leq n-1+2\sqrt{(n-1)\ln(1/\delta)} + 2\ln(1/\delta).$$

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's what I need to show. I'm sorry that I'm not very clear, perhaps I formulated the essence of the task.

This is quite an interesting assessment. And where can I get to know it in more detail?

Comment: The inequality is based on "concentration inequalities" (or also "tail bounds") on the $\chi^2$-distribution, see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables

Comment: Thank you very much for help!